# XCode6 not allowing product name to have space

Tags: ios, xcode6

XCode6 is not allowing me to add space to the product name. My project name has two words "My Country". When I'm trying to run the project its saying "clang: file not found" error. But when I checked "DerivedData" folder, I'm able to see .app file available in that folder.


Do I have to change something in the Build settings to achieve the same?

Comment: Show the complete `clang` error message.

Comment: Nope, it allows spaces and at least some of non-english characters and the build works fine. Have you recently tried to rename the project or any targets ?

Comment: @A-Live, No, I just change the "Product Name" from "MyCountry" to "My Country".

Comment: Well it should work, maybe apart from the "copy files" stage if the product with an old name was used at another target. Anyway, the full error message might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It allows to add space between words. Try by editing schema. spacing will work.